# Eclipse + M2e: JpaXmlResource cannot be cast to JpaXmlResource

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2e

Layout:

- Simple Java Maven project.
- POM contains only mimimum information incl `project.build.sourceEncoding`, no dependencies or plugins!
- `persistence.xml` under `src/main/java/META-INF`

Resulting in the following error when doing Maven - Update Project Configuration:

```
An internal error occurred during: "Updating Maven Configuration".
org.eclipse.jpt.core.resource.xml.JpaXmlResource cannot be cast to 
org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.core.resource.xml.JpaXmlResource
```

There is a reference to the first class at http://eclipsesrc.appspot.com/jsrcs/org.eclipse.jpt.core/src/org/eclipse/jpt/core/resource/xml/JpaXmlResource.java.html stating that this api is still under development.
And I've found a reference to the second class under http://wiki.eclipse.org/WTP_Provisional_API_Reduction/Indigo.

So it looks like one of some of my plugins have conflicting versions. But I'm dumbfolded as to which ones.
I've already tried updating as of today, but the error stays.

Installed versions:

```
Context and Dependency Injection Tools  1.2.0.v20120611-1827-H85-Final  org.jboss.tools.cdi.feature.feature.group   JBoss by Red Hat
Dojo Toolkit 1.7.2 (optional)   1.0.0.v20120530_1235    com.ibm.wdt.webtools.dojo.library.distributions.1.7.feature.feature.group   IBM
Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers  1.4.2.20120213-0813 epp.package.jee null
Forge Tools 1.0.0.v20120611-1732-H94-Final  org.jboss.tools.forge.feature.feature.group JBoss by Red Hat
FreeMarker IDE  1.2.0.v20120611-1732-H94-Final  org.jboss.ide.eclipse.freemarker.feature.feature.group  JBoss by Red Hat
Hibernate Tools 3.4.0.v20120611-2017-H93-Final  org.hibernate.eclipse.feature.feature.group JBoss by Red Hat
JavaHL 1.6.15 Win32 Binaries (Optional) 2.3.0.I20120316-1700    org.polarion.eclipse.team.svn.connector.javahl16.win32.feature.group    Polarion Software
JavaHL 1.7.4 Win32 Binaries (Optional)  2.3.0.I20120316-1700    org.polarion.eclipse.team.svn.connector.javahl17.win32.feature.group    Polarion Software
JBoss Archives Tools    3.2.1.v20120611-1725-H88-Final  org.jboss.ide.eclipse.archives.feature.feature.group    JBoss by Red Hat
JBoss Central   1.0.0.v20120612-0053-H99-Final  org.jboss.tools.central.feature.feature.group   JBoss by Red Hat
JBoss JAX-RS Tools  1.2.2.v20120611-1829-H137-Final org.jboss.tools.ws.jaxrs.feature.feature.group  JBoss by Red Hat
JBoss Maven CDI Configurator    1.3.0.v20120613-2141-H115-Final org.jboss.tools.maven.cdi.feature.feature.group JBoss by Red Hat
JBoss Maven Hibernate Configurator  1.3.0.v20120613-2141-H115-Final org.jboss.tools.maven.hibernate.feature.feature.group   JBoss by Red Hat
JBoss Maven Integration 1.3.0.v20120613-2141-H115-Final org.jboss.tools.maven.feature.feature.group JBoss by Red Hat
JBoss Maven JAX-RS Configurator 1.3.0.v20120613-2141-H115-Final org.jboss.tools.maven.jaxrs.feature.feature.group   JBoss by Red Hat
JBoss Maven JPA Configurator    1.3.0.v20120613-2141-H115-Final org.jboss.tools.maven.jpa.feature.feature.group JBoss by Red Hat
JBoss Maven JSF Configurator    1.3.0.v20120613-2141-H115-Final org.jboss.tools.maven.jsf.feature.feature.group JBoss by Red Hat
JBoss Maven Portlet Configurator    1.3.0.v20120613-2141-H115-Final org.jboss.tools.maven.portlet.feature.feature.group JBoss by Red Hat
JBoss Maven Project Examples    1.3.0.v20120613-2141-H115-Final org.jboss.tools.maven.project.examples.feature.feature.group    JBoss by Red Hat
JBoss Maven Seam Integration    1.3.0.v20120613-2141-H115-Final org.jboss.tools.maven.seam.feature.feature.group    JBoss by Red Hat
JBoss OpenShift Tools   2.3.0.v20120613-1951-H135-Final org.jboss.tools.openshift.express.feature.feature.group JBoss by Red Hat
JBoss Packaging Maven Configurators 1.3.0.v20120613-2141-H115-Final org.jboss.tools.maven.jbosspackaging.feature.feature.group  JBoss by Red Hat
JBoss Portlet   1.2.0.v20120611-2357-H92-Final  org.jboss.tools.portlet.feature.feature.group   JBoss by Red Hat
JBoss Runtime AS Detector   1.3.0.v20120611-2354-H105-Final org.jboss.tools.runtime.as.detector.feature.feature.group   JBoss by Red Hat
JBoss Runtime Detection Core    1.3.0.v20120611-2354-H105-Final org.jboss.tools.runtime.core.feature.feature.group  JBoss by Red Hat
JBoss Runtime Seam Detector 1.3.0.v20120611-2354-H105-Final org.jboss.tools.runtime.seam.detector.feature.feature.group JBoss by Red Hat
JBoss Tools Common - Mylyn  3.3.0.v20120611-1634-H74-Final  org.jboss.tools.common.mylyn.feature.feature.group  JBoss by Red Hat
JBoss Tools Community Project Examples  1.2.1.v20120612-0012-H106-Final org.jboss.tools.community.project.examples.feature.feature.group    JBoss by Red Hat
JBoss Tools EGit Integration (Experimental) 2.3.0.v20120613-1951-H135-Final org.jboss.tools.openshift.egit.integration.feature.feature.group    JBoss by Red Hat
JBoss Tools Java Standard Tools 3.3.0.v20120611-1739-H85-Final  org.jboss.tools.jst.feature.feature.group   JBoss by Red Hat
JBoss Tools JDT Extensions  3.3.0.v20120611-1634-H74-Final  org.jboss.tools.common.jdt.feature.feature.group    JBoss by Red Hat
JBoss Tools JSF 3.3.0.v20120611-2148-H115-Final org.jboss.tools.jsf.feature.feature.group   JBoss by Red Hat
JBoss Tools Mobile Browser Simulator    3.3.0.v20120611-1821-H102-Final org.jboss.tools.vpe.browsersim.feature.feature.group    JBoss by Red Hat
JBoss Tools RichFaces   3.3.0.v20120611-2148-H115-Final org.jboss.tools.richfaces.feature.feature.group JBoss by Red Hat
JBoss Tools Usage Reporting 1.1.0.v20120611-1654-H68-Final  org.jboss.tools.usage.feature.feature.group JBoss by Red Hat
JBoss Tools Visual Page Editor  3.3.0.v20120611-1821-H102-Final org.jboss.tools.vpe.feature.feature.group   JBoss by Red Hat
JBoss WebServices Tools 1.2.2.v20120611-1829-H137-Final org.jboss.tools.ws.feature.feature.group    JBoss by Red Hat
JBossAS Tools   2.3.0.v20120615-1559-H138-Final org.jboss.ide.eclipse.as.feature.feature.group  JBoss by Red Hat
JMX Console 1.2.0.v20120611-1733-H71-Final  org.jboss.tools.jmx.feature.feature.group   JBoss by Red Hat
m2e - slf4j over logback logging (Optional) 1.0.200.20111228-1245   org.eclipse.m2e.logback.feature.feature.group   Eclipse.org - m2e
m2e connector for build-helper-maven-plugin 0.14.0.201109282148 org.sonatype.m2e.buildhelper.feature.feature.group  Sonatype, Inc.
m2e connector for jaxb2 2.0.0.201203261829  org.bitstrings.eclipse.m2e.connectors.jaxb2.features.feature.group  bitstrings.org
m2e connector for maven-scm-plugin  1.0.0.201107091852  org.objectledge.maven.connectors.scm.feature.group  ObjectLedge.org
m2e Connector for XML Transform 0.4.0   nl.mwensveen.m2e.extras.xml.transform.feature.feature.group MWensveen.nl
Maven Integration for Eclipse JDT APT   1.0.0.201206052025  org.jboss.tools.maven.apt.feature.feature.group JBoss, by Red Hat
Maven SCM Handler for Subversive    0.13.0.201106211115 org.sonatype.m2e.subversive.feature.feature.group   Sonatype, Inc.
Native JavaHL 1.6 Implementation (Optional) 2.3.0.I20120413-1700    org.polarion.eclipse.team.svn.connector.javahl16.feature.group  Polarion Software
Native JavaHL 1.7 Implementation (Optional) 2.3.0.I20120520-1700    org.polarion.eclipse.team.svn.connector.javahl17.feature.group  Polarion Software
OSGi Application Development Tools  1.5.0.v20120530_1235    com.ibm.osgi.wdt.feature.feature.group  IBM
Project Examples    1.2.1.v20120612-0012-H106-Final org.jboss.tools.project.examples.feature.feature.group  JBoss by Red Hat
Seam 3 Tools    1.2.0.v20120611-1827-H85-Final  org.jboss.tools.cdi.seam.feature.feature.group  JBoss by Red Hat
Seam Tools  3.3.0.v20120612-1916-H130-Final org.jboss.tools.seam.feature.feature.group  JBoss by Red Hat
Spring IDE AOP Extension (optional) 2.9.2.201205070117-RELEASE  org.springframework.ide.eclipse.aop.feature.feature.group   Spring IDE Developers
Spring IDE Autowire Extension (optional)    2.9.2.201205070117-RELEASE  org.springframework.ide.eclipse.autowire.feature.feature.group  featureProvider
Spring IDE Batch Extension (optional)   2.9.2.201205070117-RELEASE  org.springframework.ide.eclipse.batch.feature.feature.group featureProvider
Spring IDE Core (required)  2.9.2.201205070117-RELEASE  org.springframework.ide.eclipse.feature.feature.group   Spring IDE Developers
Spring IDE Integration, Flex and Web Services Extension (optional)  2.9.2.201205070117-RELEASE  org.springframework.ide.eclipse.integration.feature.feature.group   featureProvider
Spring IDE OSGi Extension (optional)    2.9.2.201205070117-RELEASE  org.springframework.ide.eclipse.osgi.feature.feature.group  Spring IDE Developers
Spring IDE Security Extension (optional)    2.9.2.201205070117-RELEASE  org.springframework.ide.eclipse.security.feature.feature.group  featureProvider
Spring IDE Web Flow Extension (optional)    2.9.2.201205070117-RELEASE  org.springframework.ide.eclipse.webflow.feature.feature.group   Spring IDE Developers
Subversive SVN Connectors   2.3.0.I20120520-1700    org.polarion.eclipse.team.svn.connector.feature.group   Polarion Software
Subversive SVN Integration for the Mylyn Project (Optional) (Incubation)    0.7.9.I20110602-1700    org.eclipse.team.svn.mylyn.feature.group    Eclipse.org
Subversive SVN JDT Ignore Extensions (Optional) (Incubation)    0.7.9.I20111119-1700    org.eclipse.team.svn.resource.ignore.rules.jdt.feature.group    Eclipse.org
Subversive SVN Team Provider (Incubation)   0.7.9.I20120520-1700    org.eclipse.team.svn.feature.group  Eclipse.org
Subversive SVN Team Provider Localization (Optional) (Incubation)   0.7.9.I20120316-1700    org.eclipse.team.svn.nl1.feature.group  Eclipse.org
Subversive SVN Team Provider Sources (Incubation)   0.7.9.I20120520-1700    org.eclipse.team.svn.source.feature.group   Eclipse.org
SVNKit 1.3.7 Implementation (Optional)  2.3.0.I20120413-1700    org.polarion.eclipse.team.svn.connector.svnkit16.feature.group  Polarion Software
SVNKit 1.7.4 Implementation (Optional)  2.3.0.I20120520-1700    org.polarion.eclipse.team.svn.connector.svnkit17.feature.group  Polarion Software
Web Development Tools   1.0.0.v20120530_1235    com.ibm.wdt.webtools.top.feature.feature.group  IBM
WebSphere® Application Server V8.0 Tools    1.0.100.v20120530_1235  com.ibm.websphere.wdt.st.v8.feature.group   IBM
```